# Desactivar <input> desde Angular y que no se pueda editar en el HTML

Tags: html, angular

Quiero desactivar un input en un formulario de angular, ya lo he intentado de varias formas y nada, lo he realizado por medio de [disabled] y disabled normal en el input, pero este siempre me deja activarlo desde el html, existe alguna forma de que no se pueda activar desde el html de la página.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar usando la propiedad del siguiente modo:

```
   <input [attr.disabled]="disabled ? '' : null"/>
```

Dejo además un enlace con información sobre la propiedad **disable** que puede resultar de ayuda en caso de que estés usando angularjs: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-disabled.asp

Comment: Corrijo para ser más exacto, gracias.

Comment: Hola, lo intente pero nuevamente lo puedo desactivar desde el navegador, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.